# AS3 - Access static function through array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Currently I have an Array that is having 9 buttons pushed to it. This is called BAR.as:

```
public static var buttonArray: Array = new Array()

for(var i:int = 0; i<9; i++){
            barButton = new button
            buttonArray.push(barButton)
            buttonArray[i].name = button+(String[i])
            buttonArray[i].x = 15+(i*buttonArray[i].width)
            addChild(buttonArray[i])
        }
```

Within the class for my button I have specified an enableButton function, this is called ACTIONBARBUTTON.as:

```
public static function enableButton(shortcut:int):void{
        //instance.refreshThis(shortcut, true)
        trace("test")
    }
```

What I am trying to do is have a function that I can call to enable/disable these buttons (but not just simply ".enable"/".disable") on demand, as the content within them needs to change often. My way to do this was going to be through BAR.as:

```
public static function updateWeapons(level: int):void{
        buttonArray[level-1].enableButton(level)
    }
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property enableButton not found on src.actionbar.button and there is no default value.
at src.actionbar::bar$/updateWeapons()
at src.game::player$/levelup()
at src.game::gameplay/init()
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
at src.camera::control()
at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
at flash.display::Sprite()
at flash.display::MovieClip()
```

Just running button.enableButton(1) works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a static member function on an instance of a class.

That's why this :

```
buttonArray[level-1].enableButton(level)
```

Doesn't work. Make the enableButton function non static and it should work.

```
button.enableButton(1)
```

Works fine because you are using the class name "button" to invoke the function.

Comment: This causes issues as I have 10 "button"'s called through the Array. How would I cast "enabledButton(1)" on say, button3?

Comment: Since you are holding the buttons in an array you can do something like this :
function enableButton(index:int):void
{
    buttonArray[index].enableButton();
}

Just make sure index is not out of bounds.

Comment: The only issue then was that I had it as a static function, and not just a public function? (it works now)

Comment: Yes to call a method on an instance of a class it has to be non static. var button:Button = new Button();
button.enableButton(); 
enableButton method has to be non static.